# plus/minus vs +/- in latex preamble

Tags: macros

In the following code, I need to use +/- where I have used it, and plus/minus where I have used it.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\parindent=0 pt
\parskip=12 pt plus 0 pt minus 0 pt
\def\headsep{25pt}
\newcommand{\LAYOUT}[5]{%
  \setlength{\hoffset}{0pt}
  \setlength{\voffset}{0pt}
  \setlength{\topmargin}{#1 - 1in - \voffset - \headheight - \headsep} 
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{#2 - 1in - \hoffset}
  \setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
  \setlength{\textheight}{#3}
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#4}
  \setlength{\marginparwidth}{#5}
}
\newcommand{\FULLPAGE}{\LAYOUT{1in}{1in}{9in}{6.5in}{0.75in}}

\FULLPAGE
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

If I replace the plus and minus in line 5 with + and - I get an enigmatic 
`"missing begin{document}"` error.    If I replace the minus's in lines 10-11 with "-" I get an equally enigmatic error:

```
"Missing number, treated as zero.
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."
```

Can somebody please explain when one can use +/- and when one can use plus/minus?

Presumably there's a good reason why latex's error messages are so completely mystifying, and why inconsistencies like these keep appearing? It's really hard to explain to my coauthors, who regularly complain that latex is the most infuriating program ever devised by mankind.

Thanks very much for any advice!   Leo

Comment: They both mean different things. Plus minus are dynamic values. It is like a tolerance in which the length may change in order to fit well. If you write + and -, you are doing real math and the result should be exactly the result. You can use plus/minus in both lines, but just use them once per command. If you stay consistent you are able to do `\setlength{\parskip}{12 pt + 0 pt - 0 pt}` (which of course is just a useless example)

Comment: "latex is the most infuriating program ever devised by mankind". True. The problem is that LaTeX is macro package over TeX. The mentioned error messages are not LaTeX error messages but TeX error messages. First, learn about TeX (no LaTeX) then these messages will  be clearly understandable for you. You are right that LaTeX is infuriating, because it tries (fruitless) to hide TeX in its documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 \setlength{\topmargin}{#1 - 1in - \voffset - \headheight - \headsep}
```

is an infix expression using syntax implemented by the `calc` package that you have loaded that defines `\topmargin` to be the fixed result of that expression at this point.

```
\parskip=12 pt plus 0 pt minus 0 pt
```

is a primitive skip assignment which would be better written as

```
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
```

in LaTeX, or in this case, more simply as

```
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
```

which sets `\parskip` to be a flexible "glue" length with natural length 12pt and can shrink to 12pt-0pt and stretch to 12pt+0pt to pad out a page to the required height. As you see specifying plus or minus of 0pt is harmless but does nothing.